# How to properly track Quizzes with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to track how users progresses with my quizzes. So, I should track somehow the following information:

- quiz id
- question id
- answer user gave

Also, I should track additional information (like user started the quiz, user returned back to the previous question etc.).

I am thinking about events usage, but can not understand what to assign to `category`, `action`, `label` and `value`. The `category` could be `answer`, the `value` is the actual answer user gave, but where to pass `quiz id` and `question id`?

Answer (score 1):

Depending number of users and quiz attempted, total number of events could exceed the limits provided by analytics. In this frequent events, we need custom solution to track behaviours of users on questions.

Summary :

1.Large number of events
2. Custom tracking solution required

Answer (score 0):

These documentations should help you:

- http://www.koozai.com/blog/analytics/the-complete-google-analytics-event-tracking-guide-plus-10-amazing-examples/
- http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/03/how-to-use-events-goals-google-analytics
- https://www.hallaminternet.com/2014/using-google-analytics-event-tracking/

Presume you have a quiz with two questions. Each question has two answers. The next question you can see only after you answered the first question and clicked a link "next question".

So you should track a link "next question" with following five informations:

```
onClick=”_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘quiz’, ‘click_to_question_2’, ‘question1’, 2, true]);”
```

The value `2`, between `question1` and `true`, is the number of the answer given to the question - i.e. a number of the radio button clicked by user.